# Mono<ResponseEntity> ignored when using AWS SDK DynamoDB enhanced Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, completable-future, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am playing around with Spring WebFlux, AWS SDK 2.X, Kotlin, and DynamoDB Enhanced client. I want to return `201` with the `Location` header but I am getting a `200`. It seems that the AWS SDK is messing my actual `ResponseEntity`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
class TestController(
    private val dynamoDbAsyncTable: DynamoDbAsyncTable<TestEntity>
) {
    @PostMapping
    fun save(): Mono<ResponseEntity<Unit>> {
        // This returns 201 as expected
        // return Mono.just("someId").map { ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("/test").build() }
        // This returns 200
        return Mono.fromFuture(dynamoDbAsyncTable.putItem(TestEntity("someId"))).map { ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("/test")).build<Unit>() }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: whats `<Unit>`?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say this is Kotlin

Comment: Well are you putting something in the body?

Comment: The body is empty

Comment: You might try to use `thenReturn` operator instead of `map`. My guess is that the DynamoDB put operation returns a `null` as a `Void` which makes the `Mono` empty. Since `Mono` is empty, the `map` operator is not triggered. You can overcome this by using `thenReturn` which is used on empty completion as well.